# Get value by column name value

Tags: php, laravel

Ny array looks something like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2052 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\NewsMeta {#2089 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\NewsMeta {#2090 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\NewsMeta {#2091 ▶}
  ]
}
```

If I open up the array 2:

```
 #original: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 17
        "post_id" => 240231
        "news_tag_id" => 5
        "meta_name" => "_thumbnail_id"
        "meta_value" => "240232"
        "created_at" => "2020-08-06 22:34:06"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-06 22:34:06"
      ]
```

Now, I looking to get value "240232" given that I've 240231.

How do I search inside array of the object?
Something like: where post_id is 240231 get ts meta_value.

FYI: It's not eloquent or DB query.

Comment: In JS you could use Array.find. Unfortunately, PHP's `array_search` doesn't take a callback, but `array_filter` does. You could use that to filter it down to 1 record. Or just write a loop and break out of it once you find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the collection [`firstWhere()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-first-where) method

```php
$collection->firstWhere('post_id', '240231')['meta_value'] ?? null;
```

With the data you provided this should return `240232`. In a dataset where there is no `post_id = 240231` it would return `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
        $postId = 240231;
        $metaValue = null;
        foreach ($collection as $model) {
            if ($model->post_id == $postId) {
              $metaValue = $model->meta_value;
              break;
            }
        }
        echo $metaValue;
```

You could also use the collection's [seach](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-search) method:

```
    $postId = 240231;
    $metaValue = $collection->search(static function($model, $key) use($postId) {
        if ($model->post_id == $postId) {
            return $model->meta_value;
        }
    });
    echo $metaValue;
```

Comment: Is there any other way than looping?

Comment: @NishDekardo There are some helper methods like array_filter that mpen mentioned, but most are going to use a loop internally anyway.  You could also write it so that the original query that provided the collection uses a where clause so you get the record you want straight away and can call `->pluck('meta_value')` on the single record. But it sounds like you may not want that

Comment: the problem is I've about 200 items in an array so I'm just hesitant to loop. Also plucking will do no good as I still need other items that isn't limit to meta_value.

Comment: @NishDekardo Yeah, a loop is about your only option here. But note that the "break" will break out of the loop once a match is found so that will help some. Honestly though, php will loop through those 200 items in probably less than a second. I doubt you'd ever have any issues unless you were looping through thousands.